# Is there any limitation of using SharePoint Boolean Yes/No column type

Tags: sharepoint-online, boolean-field

I rely a lot on the SharePoint Boolean Yes/No column type:-

[image]

now i were reading this article and other articles https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Delegation-warning-for-calculated-column/td-p/470520 , and they advice to stay way of using calculated columns and Yes/No column.. but i am not sure why the Boolean column type should be avoided? although based on my test i can do this filtering without any delegation warnings :-

[image]

so i can get the items which are Not draft + Are rejected + Title = Test... so what is the limitation of using Yes/no SharePoint column type? and do we really need to avoid using them?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a limit to this column type, but there is a limit to the size per column.
[image]
[image]

Reference: [Column limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-limits-2019#column-limits)